# Extracting HTML table into R

Tags: html, xml, r, html-parsing, rcurl

I've been trying to extract a table from a webpage. The data is a flight track data from live flight tracking website (https://flightaware.com/live/flight/WJA1508/history/20150814/1720Z/CYYC/KSFO/tracklog).

I've tried XML, RCurl and Curl packages, but I didn't work. I believe most likely because I couldn't figure out how to avoid the SSL as well as the columns that contains notes on the flight status (i. e., first two from the top and third from the bottom of the table).

Can any one knows how extract this table int R?

Comment: It works better if you share what you have tried so far.

Comment: They have an [API](http://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/pricing_class.rvt) that (yes) is a pay-for thing, but that is probably why they do explicitly tell you in item 6 of http://flightaware.com/about/termsofuse that scraping is a violation of ToS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @hrbrmstr in the comments above, this violates FlightAware's TOS, but what you do with your code is your business. :) This should get you most of the way there using the `rvest` package:

```
library(rvest)

u <- "https://flightaware.com/live/flight/WJA1508/history/20150814/1720Z/CYYC/KSFO/tracklog"

html_read <- html(u)
tbl <- html_table(
  html_nodes(html_read, "table"), 
  fill=TRUE, 
  header=FALSE, 
  trim=TRUE 
)[[2]]

##  Subset to the first row of data and remove all extra
##    columns:
tbl_o <- tbl[6:nrow(tbl), ]
tbl_o <- tbl_o[,colSums(is.na(tbl_o))!=nrow(tbl_o)]

names(tbl_o) <- c(
  "Time", "Lat", "Lon", 
  "Course", "Direction", 
  "KTS", "MPH", "Alt", 
  "Rate", "Location"
)

str(tbl_o)
```

Which yields:

```
'data.frame':   292 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Time     : chr  "Fri 01:41:34 PM" "Fri 01:48:59 PM" "Fri 01:49:14 PM" "Fri 01:50:05 PM" ...
 $ Lat      : chr  "51.0833" "51.1551" "51.1683" "51.2235" ...
 $ Lon      : chr  "-113.9667" "-114.0209" "-114.0209" "-114.0220" ...
 $ Course   : chr  "335°" "0°" "0°" "358°" ...
 $ Direction: chr  "Northwest" "North" "North" "North" ...
 $ KTS      : chr  "20" "201" "219" "149" ...
 $ MPH      : chr  "23" "231" "252" "171" ...
 $ Alt      : chr  "3,500" "4,900" "5,200" "6,800" ...
 $ Rate     : chr  "" "222" "1,727" "1,701" ...
 $ Location : chr  "Edmonton Center" "FlightAware ADS-B  (CYYC)" "FlightAware ADS-B  (CYYC)" "FlightAware ADS-B  (CEG2)" ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Forrest! This is exactly what I wanted to do :)

Comment: You're very welcome, I've battled those details in the past, it's nice to have a good starting point to work from. :)